# QEMU: unable to mount USB device to VM

Tags: usb, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I want to passthru an USB stick to my VM running in plain QEMU.

Here is the device from the host system:

```
 ~ $ lsusb -t 
 /:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
     |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M

 ~ $ lsusb | grep lash
 Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
```

Now trying in QEMU monitor:

```
device_add qemu-xhci,id=xhci
```

after that all attempts fail

```
device_add usb-host,hostbus=4,hostaddr=2
Error: failed to open host usb device 4:2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that problem only with latter hot-add via the monitor, or does it also occur when you start your qemu right away with e.g. `-device usb-host,hostbus=4,hostaddr=2`?

Comment: "hot plug" so to say - haven't yet tried with this device but the qemu cli start commnad works with other devices (tested the stick again - FAT32 and working in linux)